# Reindexing Theorem Numbers

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

The `amsthm` package comes with an several theorem-like environments. Is there a way to adjust the indexing on a sequence of theorems to skip a number? That is, I would like to have it do something like this,

Theorem 1.

Theorem 3.

Theorem 4.

without having anything appearing in between Theorem 1 and Theorem 3.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is the number 2 used for some other environment and do you want to share the number? If yes then `amsmath` lets you do this.

Comment: No, I just want to skip it. I'm taking a test where I only have to answer some of the questions, and wanted the problem numbers on my solutions to correspond to the problem numbers on the test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\stepcounter{theorem}` after Theorem 1.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there should be an easy way to do that.

Comment: wouldn't you want `\refstepcounter`?

Comment: @cmhughes: I didn't think of that, but actually, you wouldn't.  `\refstepcounter` sets the current label, and therefore, after calling it, every `\label` command until the next `\refstepcounter` (a section or another theorem) will incorrectly point to the nonexistent Theorem 2.  Theorem 3 itself will `\refstepcounter` in the correct place.

Comment: Actually, it's even worse than that, since if you are calling `\refstepcounter` in the global context, it requires another globally-scoped `\refstepcounter` to override it.  So only another section will do (inside of environments it can be overridden locally).  Of course, most of the time you don't have `\label`s flying around in the middle of the text, but it's still philosophically wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification- an interesting discussion :) +1 from me